# Can small changes be made to a published app without needing the user to update to a new version

Tags: android, flutter, dart, build, publish

I am yet to publish an app (the final stages are being built using Flutter and Android Studio) but once the app is launched and live, are there any changes that can be done without the need for a full blown update, and the requirement of a user to update the app (if they have auto-update off)?

For example if you notice a spelling mistake, or a list of options a user chooses needs updating, or a color needs changing?

Can small changes such as these be 'pushed' out to all users regardless of whether they have auto-update on or off, or do all change regardless how small require a new version of the app and for users to update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> are there any changes that can be done without the need for a full blown update

no.

only if this comes from an api (for example, if you pull your strings or colors from an api service), then you can easily change *what the api returns to your app*, otherwise you'll need an update.

Any changes you make will result in changes to your generated apk, which is a completely new file containing content which users don't have, so they'll have to retrieve these changes through an update